# not enough master nodes discovered during pinging - Elasticsearch cluster self signed certificate

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, search-guard

I used SearchGuard to encrypt nodes in ElasticSearch cluster following [this guide](https://gryzli.info/2018/12/01/elasticsearchelk-stack-security-howto/)

Master:

```
cluster.name: client1
searchguard.enterprise_modules_enabled: false


node.name: ekl.test.com
node.master: true
node.data: true
node.ingest: true


network.host: 0.0.0.0

#http.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: ["ekl1.test1.com","ekl.test.com"]



http.port: 9200


discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ekl.test.com", "ekl1.test1.com"]


discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

xpack.security.enabled: false


searchguard.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node1.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: 'ssl/node1.key'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.transport.resolve_hostname: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node1_http.pem'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node1_http.key'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.nodes_dn:
- CN=ekl.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
- CN=ekl1.test1.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
- CN=admin.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear Com\, Inc.,DC=example,DC=com
```

Node:

```
cluster.name: client1
searchguard.enterprise_modules_enabled: false


node.name: ekl1.test.com
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false


network.host: 0.0.0.0

#http.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: ["ekl1.test1.com","ekl.test.com"]



http.port: 9200


discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ekl.test.com", "ekl1.test1.com"]


discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

xpack.security.enabled: false


searchguard.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node2.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: 'ssl/node2.key'
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.transport.resolve_hostname: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node2_http.pem'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/node2_http.key'
searchguard.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: '/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/root-ca.pem'
searchguard.nodes_dn:
- CN=ekl.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
- CN=ekl1.test1.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear BG\, Ltd.,DC=BugBear,DC=com
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
- CN=admin.test.com,OU=Ops,O=BugBear Com\, Inc.,DC=example,DC=com
Certificates are self-signed
```

From node i can telnet to ports 9200/9300 by hostnames i can ping and

curl -kvX GET "https://admin:pass@ekl.test.com:9200" works fine.
Errors on node:

[ekl1.test1.com] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [], but needed [1](https://gryzli.info/2018/12/01/elasticsearchelk-stack-security-howto/)), pinging again

Both server names are correct

I suspect issue is in self-signed certificate i imported it in trusted root CA anchor but error remained.

If i specify IP instead of hostnames then getting:

Illegal parameter in http or transport request found.
This means that one node is trying to connect to another with
a non-node certificate (no OID or searchguard.nodes_dn incorrect configured) or that someone
is spoofing requests.

> ES Config path is /etc/elasticsearch
>   [2019-03-28T21:25:56,450][INFO ][c.f.s.s.DefaultSearchGuardKeyStore] >[ekl1.test1.com] OpenSSL not available (this is not an error, we simply >fallback to built-in JDK SSL) because of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: >io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: had to add to non-master:

```
transport.tcp.port: 9300
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ekl.test.com:9300"]
transport.host: ekl1.test1.com
```